# decoding issue with diacritic characters

Tags: java, string, utf-8, character-encoding

What is the difference between these two below strings? When I decode first string then it works fine and I can see diachritic characters showing up fine.

```
String val = "m%C3%B6torhead album";
String decodedVal = URLDecoder.decode(val, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But when I try to decode below string then I don't see diachritic characters working fine.

```
String val = "m%EF%BF%BDtorhead album";
String decodedVal = URLDecoder.decode(val, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? These strings we are getting from upstream so we don't have control on that.

Comment: The characters must also be available in the used font to see them. What exactly do you mean by "don't see diachritic characters working fine"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sequence decodes to U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, which is used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode.

This means you may see something like �.

There is nothing you could do on the client to fix that, the problem is on the server and needs to be fixed there.

Comment: The cause being a failed conversion like from pasted text: `Mœtorhead` as pure Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1), as `œ` is not present in ISO-8859-1, but in Windows-Latin-1 aka (Cp-1252). That might be the case here, though I thought it was Motörhead. (Mind that browsers interprete ISO-8859-1 as Cp-1252, so server-side handling should in fact use Cp-1252 for client side ISO-8859-1.)

Answer (score 0):

%C3%B6 is a valid encoded value for character ö so the value "m%C3%B6torhead album" is decoding perfectly.
In second case "%EF%BF%BD" is not a valid encoded value for any characterset in UTF-8 encoding so it is not decoding it.